# How to run ansible playbook in kmv created with terraform

Tags: ansible, terraform, kvm

After I created a vm with terraform, I want to run a ansible playbook which installs a lamp server in the vm created with kvm provider in the same .tf file, but I dont know the ip of the new vm until I run : `virsh net-dhcp-leases default`.
I want to add in the end of the tf file a code like this one that executes playbook in the same vm created:

```
provisioner “local-exec” {
 command = “ansible-playbook -u ubuntu -i ‘variable that specify the ip of created vm’ main.yml”
 }
```

thank you

Comment: Why not use the user-data for that? Assuming AWS: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#user_data

Comment: How will I use it ? I'm working in KVM

Comment: Can you add a bit more code of your vm with terraform

Comment: @HelderSepulveda
'''resource "libvirt_domain" "test-domain" {
 name = "guest-${count.index + 1}"
 memory = "1024"
 vcpu = 1

 #add the cloud init disk to share user data
 cloudinit = libvirt_cloudinit_disk.commoninit[count.index].id

 #set to default libvirt network
 network_interface {
  network_name= "default"
 }

 console {
  type = "pty"
  target_type = "serial"
  target_port = "0"
 }

 disk {
  volume_id = element(libvirt_volume.image-qcow2.*.id, count.index + 1)
 }
 
 graphics {
  type = "spice"
  listen_type = "adress"
  autoport = true
 }
 count = 2

}'''

Comment: Look at some of the examples that use user_data:
https://github.com/dmacvicar/terraform-provider-libvirt/blob/19c23424ccfdecf6dfcbdd87783bf835ba5f585e/examples/v0.12/ubuntu/ubuntu-example.tf#L32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way:
IP-adresses are given some time after creating the VM in KVM( if dhcp), so i recommend running everything in a shell script.

in TF-script add output module( fetch IPs)

```
output "ips" {
  # show IP, run 'terraform refresh' if not populated
  value = libvirt_domain.domain-ubuntu.*.network_interface.0.addresses
}
```

shell script:

```
terraform apply
#sleep to wait for IPs(if dhcp)
sleep 30
#fetch IPs
terraform refresh | grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' >> hosts
ansible-playbook -u ubuntu -i hosts
```